# First page in php

Tags: php

I am just trying to create my first php page. Created a folder named myfirstproject in `www` folder in wamp. Inside this folder i want to create a helloworld type of page. But i am not able to save any file inside that folder. I am using windows 7. Then i created a simple html page and notepad and tried to save in that folder, but now i get some permissions error. How do i solve this?

Also, which is the most widely used IDE or editor for php? And which are best frameworks that people currently use in industry?

Comment: Too many questions at once and all of them have been answered before too.

Comment: If you're going to vote to close a question, at least put why.

Comment: Gordon, as PHP has no built-in support for multithreading. :-)

Comment: So you have a windows file permission problem. Which is not related to php at all.

Answer (score 2):

The greatest IDEs for PHP, in my opinion, are the following:

1. PhpStorm - wins on all accounts. Commercial, but for its price, it's totally worth it.
2. Aptana Studio 1.5 (lacks PHP support as of 2.0, only way you will use its full features for PHP editing is by searching an archived version with PHP installed, on some tracker or something like that)
3. VS.PHP (plugin for Microsoft Visual Studio, Commercial licence)
4. Zend Studio (commercial, based on Eclipse, like Aptana)
5. NetBeans
6. Eclipse PDT

The others I could hardly call IDE, but rather simple editors.

As for the access. If you have UAC activated, and the www folder is protected, you might need to run Notepad as administrator to be able to edit. Or just verify that your user has permission to modify files in that folder.

Answer (score 1):

Propably this directory is owned by the Administrator and you are the user. Fix it.

Answer (score 1):

Answer to second part of your question: Have a look at this short article: [Seven great PHP IDEs compared](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/opensource/library/os-php-ide/index.html) from IBM.

They reffer to the following IDEs:

- Eclipse
- Komodo
- PHP Designer
- PhpED
- PHPEdit
- Zend Studio

There are lots of pros and cons for each of them. I myself use PHPEclipse which works great for me.